# [__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:]: index 9223372036854775807 beyond bounds [0 .. 13]'

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

I have an SQLite database implemented in my xcode project. i want to view all name from database into tableview but getting an error as

> NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:]: index
>   9223372036854775807 beyond bounds [0 .. 13]'

```html
@interface DisplayViewController ()
@property (nonatomic, strong) DBManager *dbManager;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSArray *arrPeopleInfo;
  @end

@implementation DisplayViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.mytableview.delegate = self;
    self.mytableview.dataSource = self;
    
    NSString *docsDir;
    NSArray *dirPaths;
    
    
    //Get the directory
    dirPaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    docsDir = dirPaths[0];
     self.dbManager = [[DBManager alloc] initWithDatabaseFilename:@"IApp.db"];    //Build the path to keep the database
   // _databasePath = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:[docsDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"IApp.db"]];
   // [self getcount];
    [self loadData];
   // [self getcount];
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}


      
- (void)loadData {
    // Form the query.
    NSString *query = @"select * from iApp";
    
   
    if (self.arrPeopleInfo != nil) {
        self.arrPeopleInfo = nil;
    }
    self.arrPeopleInfo = [[NSArray alloc] initWithArray:[self.dbManager loadDataFromDB:query]];
    
    [self.mytableview reloadData];
}
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    //#warning Potentially incomplete method implementation.
    // Return the number of sections.
    return  1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return self.arrPeopleInfo.count;
    // return [arri count];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"idCellRecord" forIndexPath:indexPath];
    
    NSInteger indexOfname = [self.dbManager.arrColumnNames indexOfObject:@"firstname"];
    NSInteger indexOffname = [self.dbManager.arrColumnNames indexOfObject:@"lastname"];
  
    cell.textLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@", [[self.arrPeopleInfo objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectAtIndex:indexOfname], [[self.arrPeopleInfo objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectAtIndex:indexOffname]];
    
    
    return cell;
      
}
```

Answer (score 2):

When you search for an item in something, Cocoa returns `NSNotFound` for the index, if the method cannot find the item. This applies for `-indexOfObject:`, too. `NSNotFound` is a big integral number (`INT_MAX`) as you can see in the title of your Q.

Therefore

```
NSInteger indexOfname = [self.dbManager.arrColumnNames indexOfObject:@"firstname"];
```

will be `NSNotFound`, if `@"firstName"` is not found in the receiver. Please check, whether you have such a key. Typo? Camel case? `first`*`N`*`ams`?

If you do not know the keys at compile time you have to check for it, as @Inder told you:

```
if(indexOfname==NSNotFound)
  // The object is not present
```

BTW: You should really recheck your naming. It does not follow the Cocoa naming conventions.

Answer (score 0):

Please check whether `indexOfname` or `indexOffname` is equal to `NSNotFound`

```
NSInteger indexOfname = [self.dbManager.arrColumnNames indexOfObject:@"firstname"];
NSInteger indexOffname = [self.dbManager.arrColumnNames indexOfObject:@"lastname"];

if (indexOfname == NSNotFound) {
  //Then don't use this index
}

if (indexOffname == NSNotFound) {
  //Then don't use this index
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can prevent this by using a very simple checking.

```
if(indexOfname < [self.dbManager.arrColumnNames count] && indexOffname < [self.dbManager.arrColumnNames count]) {
    cell.textLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@", [[self.arrPeopleInfo objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectAtIndex:indexOfname], [[self.arrPeopleInfo objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectAtIndex:indexOffname]];     
}
else {
    cell.textLabel.text = @""; // or what ever you want to do
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually  you have successfully fetched all record from `Database`. so left part is how to shown in `UITableViewCell`. modified `cellForRowAtIndexPath` as per below code.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

       UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"idCellRecord" forIndexPath:indexPath];


       cell.textLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@", [[self.arrPeopleInfo objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] valeuForKey:@"firstname"], [[self.arrPeopleInfo objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] valueForKey:@"lastname"]];


return cell;

}
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/75528/discussion-on-answer-by-none-nsarraym-objectatindex-index-9223372036854775).